# Dashboard extension for Chrome as a new tab or popup supporting bookmarks, apps, etc

Tags: chrome, productivity, bookmark

I am looking for a Chrome extension that I can use as a Dashboard. I used Humble New Tab page before but I wonder if there are better options.

It should support:

- Bookmarks (optionally recent bookmarks and other devices)
- Bookmark bar
- Most visited pages
- Closed tabs
- Apps (optional)
- Organizing bookmarks
- New Tab replacement (optionally popup mode)

It should be fast as I cannot wait more than a second for the new tab to open.

Thank you  :)

Answer (score 1):

Try [**Fold Dashboard**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fold-new-tab-dashboard-fo/gfaneniadbhfdegjkgjefacoiafhmola). It has almost all the features you want. You can organize the bookmarks but cannot edit them at this point. Please leave a good review on Chrome Store if you find it helpful.

Disclaimer: I am the author of the extension.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was exactly what I was looking for :)